# Gitlab CI Runner with tag

Tags: ios, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, apple-m1

I am trying now 100 times an dont get it, maybe someone can help me out

I have a CI Job in Gitlab which should run on a specific runner that is installed on an OSx System but the job doesnt appaer in the gitlab pipeline ui when I start the pipeline.

Here My gitlab-ci.yml:

```
app-ios:
  stage: build
  script:
  - echo 'test'
  tags:
    - apple
    - shell
  only:
    - deploy/app
```

I tried register again the runner
I tried register with only one tag

Comment: The Runner also shows in the logs checking for jobs... nothing

Comment: I assume the runner is registered and available for that project?

Comment: Yes, if go under CI / CD Settings from projects the runner is listed and has status green last connected 2 min ago :(

Answer (score 3):

When adding [tags to your CI YAML file](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#tags), you want to make sure that your runner has the corresponding tags.

From the docs,

> a runner must be assigned every tag listed in the job.

So in your case, you want to make sure that the registered runner also has both the tags `apple` and `shell`. Obviously, the runner can have more tags, but it needs to have at least those two.